# I wrote a recursive search function in python. Why does it complete in Jupyter Notebook successfully, but error out in pycharm with a stack overflow

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, pycharm

Jupyter notebook and pycharm are both using the same interpreter, so what else could cause the different behaviour?

Comment: You probably won't get a meaningful answer without at least showing a [mre] and more details of your code that has this problem. Please see [ask]
and the [question checklist](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/260648/843953)

Comment: The [limit can be changed in any interpreter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3323001/what-is-the-maximum-recursion-depth-in-python-and-how-to-increase-it), so Jupyter might be doing just that.

Comment: @MatsLindh -- Thanks; I didn't even know that was possible. If you write a short answer I'll be happy to upvote it.